# PostBackUrl does not fire after introducing the client side javascript confirmation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, grid, telerik

I have a telerik grid with lots of rows.  I also have a delete button:

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" UniqueName="GridButtonDelete" CommandName="Delete">
```

I initially had code in the PostBackUrl. After the delete button was clicked I successfuly went to another page, and I did what I had to do. However, I have decided to add a client side confirmation

```
(item["GridButtonDelete"].Controls[0] as ImageButton).OnClientClick = "return confirm ('OK to Delete?');";
```

Once the confirmation was added the PostBackUrl of the delete button does not fire.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had issues with this before as well. Try this out instead.

```
OnClientClick="if(!confirm('OK to Delete?'))return false;"
```

Comment: Thanks man.  I am confused what I did wrong here but what you said worked!

Comment: Your welcome! I dont really understand why it has an issue with they way you tried. You did the same thing I did when I initially tried it.